# Struggling with Java binding (Using Xamarin Android)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I removed some namespaces in Metadata.xml while binding a java library like:

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.payu.india.Tasks']/class[@name='VerifyPaymentTask']" />
```

After that java library successfully bind with my xamarin's java binding project, then I referenced that java binding project's dll with my demo project then I got error like:

> Error 1: 'Com.Payu.India.Tasks.VerifyPaymentTask' does not implement
>   inherited abstract member 'Android.OS.AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params
>   Java.Lang.Object[])' PayU
>   Integration\PayUSdkLib\PayUSdkLib\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Payu.India.Tasks.VerifyPaymentTask.cs
>   9 23 PayUSdkLib

Can anyone please help me that how can I solve this type of error?

Comment: you need to look at the method signature for that method in your binding and see how it differs from the java method.

Comment: Can you please explain your comment @Jason

Comment: The error message is telling you there is a mismatch between the method signature in your binding class and how it is defined in the Java library.  You need to figure out what the difference is - knowing that, then you can determine how to fix it.  This commit shows many common issues and how to fix them: https://gist.github.com/brendanzagaeski/9607158

Comment: But @Jason i havn't any source code of java jar file, i only have the .jar file  so can't view the source code....

Comment: presumably they provide documentation for their API that shows the public methods and their signatures?